# Events of adding/editing catalog rule

Tags: event-observer, catalog-price-rules

Are there any event will be dispatched after the user adding/editing the rules in Promotions->Catalog price rules/Shopping cart price rules, i'm going to write a module to log these actions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hook onto the event: `salesrule_rule_save_after` and `catalogrule_rule_save_after` for shopping cart and catalog rules respectively. Also, to just be on the safe side you could check in the observer you are going to create that the **admin session is active** before you log what you need to from the admin session.

The model corresponding to the Shopping cart rules is `salesrule/rule` and it has a `event prefix` of `salesrule_rule` so whenever this model is saved the event : `salesrule_rule_save_after` will be dispatched.

Comment: how about adminhtml_controller_salesrule_prepare_save?

Comment: This wouldn't work for catalog pricing rules.

Answer (score 4):

I think you can use `catalogrule_rule_save_before` and `catalogrule_rule_save_after`.
You can get the rule object in your observer like this:

```
public function doSomething($observer) {
    $rule = $observer->getEvent()->getRule();
    //do something with $rule
}
```

Comment: how about adminhtml_controller_salesrule_prepare_save?

Comment: @hkinterview. That could work. But that won't get dispatched if I call `$rule->save()` from outside the admin controller. In the way I described it, it works independently from the place you call the `save`.